# How to reduce PowerShell CPU spikes

Tags: powershell, cpu-usage

On a windows server 2008R2 (VM, only 1CPU), I'm noticing hefty CPU spikes, completely disabling signing in via RDP / freezing connected sessions. Logging shows the ESX CPU demand scratches 3000 points for minutes.
I'm regularly starting PowerShell background jobs via the scheduler.
I already start the PowerShell jobs with the -NoProfile parameter, anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to dramatically reduce the CPU usage (max 700 ESX) by adding the parameters -NoLogo -NonInteractive.